# Scripting Windows 2008 R2 restore of files using wbadmin

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backup-restoration, windows-server-backup, wbadmin

The problem I am running into is the restoration of files using wbadmin; specifically with the -recoverytarget flag set. The line that I am running is :

> e:>WBADMIN START RECOVERY -version:09/19/2013-10:00 -itemType:File -items:E:\Directory\ExcelSheet.xls -recoverytarget:e:\Temp

After this has executed, a nice message is displayed

> Retrieving volume information...
>   You have chosen to recover the file(s) E:\Vendor\ExcelSheet.xls from the backup created on 9/19/2013 6:00 AM to e:\temp.
>
> Do you want to continue?
>   [Y] Yes [N] No y

I select Y and hit enter and this is displayed :

> The path specified for recovery is invalid.

All combinations of trailing slashes have been tried but the same behavior occurs. UNC paths for the '-recoverytarget' are not supported.

Permissions are also not an issue as the targetdirectory has been given full rights to everyone (for testing of course).

File recovery from the GUI is functioning perfectly fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message on Windows Server 2012 R2.

In my case, it turned out the message was misleading! The error was a typo in the `-items` specification (i forgot one level of folder nesting), not in the `-recoveryTarget` value.

It looks like the message should be read as: "One of the paths of the items you specified for recovery is invalid."

Answer (score -2):

Add "-quiet", it will suppress the prompts.

Comment: Running with -quiet will get rid of the 'Do you want to continue? [Y] Yes [N] No' prompt but the same error is the end result

Comment: Does it work if you recover it back to the source?  (I know this isn't what you asked for) Also does adding double quotes around the paths help? "E:\temp"  Could it be it is complaining about the source and not the destination?  The error is a bit ambiguous.  Also, what are you trying accomplish?  It looks a bit like this might be one of those cases where enabling volume shadow copy might be a better way? (but I don't know your exact reasons for wanting to restore a file like this).